# Loading taxonomy terms in a tree in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have multiple level of vocabulary, I want to display all level in the hierarchy same as taxonomy display. My taxonomy is like.

```
All
   Drinks
      Alcohol Drinks
         Beer
         Vodka
      Alcohol Free Drinks
         Coca Cola
         Pepsi
   Fruits
      Fruits For Losing Weight
         Watermelon
         Blackberrie
      Fruits For Dogs
         Strawberry
         Orange
```

now I am trying to load this using code.

```
$vid = 'food';
    $terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, 0, 1, FALSE);
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_data_1[$term->tid] = $term->name;
            $terms_2 =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, $term->tid, 1, FALSE);
            foreach ($terms_2 as $term_2) {
                $term_data_2[$term_2->tid] = $term_2->name;
                    $terms_3 =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, $term_2->tid, 1, FALSE);
                    foreach ($terms_3 as $term_3) {
                        $term_data_3[$term_3->tid] = $term_3->name;
                    }

            }
            $term_data_1[$term_2->tid] = $term_data_2;
            $term_data_1[$term_3->tid] = $term_data_3;
    }

    kint($term_data_1);
```

and this code giving result like

[image]

Need help to get term in hierarchy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[TermForm.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21TermForm.php/8.2.x) has an example of how to do this.

Basically you loop through the tree and add dashes according to the depth of the term.

Here's an example you can use:

```
$options = [];
foreach (\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid) as $item) {
  $options[$item->tid] = str_repeat('-', $item->depth) . $item->name;
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you want a nested array of terms, you can do like this:

```
$result = [];
foreach (\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid) as $item) {
  $parents = array_reverse(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadAllParents($item->tid), TRUE);
  $r = &$result;
  foreach ($parents as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($r[$k])) {
      $r[$k] = array_replace($r[$k], [$k => $v->label()]);
    }
    else {
      $r[$k] = [$k => $v->label()];
    }
    $r = &$r[$k];
  }
}
```

That will work regardless of how many levels your terms are nested.

Comment: I got that actually I dont want to make (-) I want hierarchy taxonomy array in the dpm, thats why I post image also, there inner level are not coming in correct hierarchy level.

Answer (score 3):

I created a simple service to get a nested tree of taxonomy terms. It returns an array of taxonomy terms, with each term having an extra `children` property, which is an array of terms again having a `children` property.

```php
/**
 * Class TaxonomyUtils
 */
class TaxonomyUtils {
  
  /**
   * @var \Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorage
   */
  protected $taxonomyStorage;

  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityTypeManager) {
    $this->taxonomyStorage = $entityTypeManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
  }

  /**
   * @param string $vocabulary
   * @param int $parent
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function getTree(string $vocabulary, int $parent = 0) {
    $terms = $this->taxonomyStorage->loadTree($vocabulary, $parent, 1, TRUE);
    $tree = [];

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $term->children = $this->getTree($vocabulary, $term->id());
      $tree[$term->id()] = $term;
    }

    return $tree;
  }

}
```

#### my_module.services.yml

```yaml
services:
  my_module.taxonomy_utils:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Utils\TaxonomyUtils
    arguments: [ '@entity_type.manager' ]
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  The output is much more intuitive than some of the other solutions.  I added some code to capture the active trail too, since I'm using it for a custom menu.  Gist here in case it helps anyone: https://gist.github.com/jhume/b5739a0ebd76c39ee3dfa24deff04dc2

Answer (score 0):

You should use Multi Dimensional array for storing data.

```
  $vid = 'tags';
  $terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, 0, 1);
  $termDataAll = [];
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $termDataAll[$term->tid]["tid"] = $term->tid;
    $termDataAll[$term->tid]["name"] = $term->name;
     $terms_2 =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, $term->tid, 1);
      foreach($terms_2 as $term_2){
        $termDataAll[$term->tid][$term_2->tid]["tid"] = $term_2->tid;
        $termDataAll[$term->tid][$term_2->tid]["name"] = $term_2->name;
        $terms_3 =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, $term_2->tid, 1);
        foreach($terms_3 as $term_3){
          $termDataAll[$term->tid][$term_2->tid][$term_3->tid]["tid"] = $term_3->tid;
          $termDataAll[$term->tid][$term_2->tid][$term_3->tid]["name"] = $term_3->name;
        }
      }
  }
  dpm($termDataAll);
```

Comment: This would not work if the array tree is nested 4 levels.

Comment: The code can be modified for any number of levels by adding required number of for loops similarly.

Comment: I know. This code might work, but it's not really nice to have some code that won’t work if they add mare levels of terms. It would be better to handle all possible solutions with one chunk of code.